# how to jquery ui autocomplete for element created after document ready?

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete

I have one main search input field and it is written in index.php:

```
<div class="row ">
    <input class="col-10 col-md-10 form-control form-control-sm w-8"
        type="text" name="tag_search" id="tag-search" value="" placeholder="Search..." >
    <button class="col-2 col-md-2 btn btn-search" type="button" onclick="searchFunc()" ><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>
    <div id="suggestions"></div>
</div>
```

and autocomplete works for it
but I have another input that is created afterward when an image is displayed
and it suggests adding a tag to it
and they both have the same autocomplete function ,  (with identifiers different)
but it does not work for the later. I suspect  because it is created dynamically.

```
$( function() {
    $( "#tag-search" ).autocomplete({
        appendTo: "#suggestions",
        source: function( request, response ) {
        $.ajax( {
          url: "/includes/autocomplete.php",
          dataType: "json",
          data: {
            term: request.term
          },
        success: function( data ) {
           response( data );
         }
       } );
    },
    minLength: 2,
    select: function( event, ui ) {
    }
  } );
} );
```

second element:

```
 <input type="text" class="form-control"  id="add-tag-name" placeholder="Add Tag...">
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary "
  title="Add Tag" id="plusbutton" onclick="addTagFunc()"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i>
</button>
<div id="tagsuggestions"></div>
```

second function:

```
$( function() {
$( "#add-tag-name" ).autocomplete({
  appendTo: "#tagsuggestions",
  source: function( request, response ) {
    $.ajax( {
      url: "/includes/autocomplete.php",
      dataType: "json",
      data: {
        term: request.term
      },
      success: function( data ) {
        response( data );
      }
    } );
  },
  minLength: 2,
  select: function( event, ui ) {
  }
} );
} );
```

Comment: Well `$( "#tag-search" )` will only identify a single element (because HTML Ids must be unique), so this code will never work for any other inputs, no matter when they are created.

Comment: yes as I said to each element I created a function. but that is not the problem

Comment: you've only shown one function, and your question said "they both have the same function". So I assumed you were trying to share this code between two elements. If you have some other code which is not working, you need to show that code. Your working code is not very interesting to us, we need to see the bits which are causing a problem.

Comment: if we define a function for an element that is not yet created. will it be ignored or will it trigger when said element is created?

Comment: It will be ignored, because when you define the event handler, it can only attach to elements which already exist in the DOM. You can get round this problem though - google "jquery delegated event handling", there are plenty of examples already.

Comment: could you please suggest me some example , I changed it to `$('#tag-add-name').on('click',function...` but still not working

Comment: thank you. as a matter of fact that link is exactly what I read before  commenting. the idea is to delegate from an already existing container so `$('#existingcontainer').on(('click','input',function ...` worked for me

Comment: exactly. Glad you solved it.